# How to find CGI version in IIS

Tags: iis, cgi, windows-server

We have got a sonatype security issue with CGI. We need to know the CGI version in IIS or windows server. How can I get it?

Comment: What issue are you talking about? The actual CVE should have all details like Windows/IIS versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGI stand for Common Gateway Interface. It is used by webserver to pass web user request to application server and process and give back the output.it is a part of http protocol. It has no version; the settings are determined by the version of IIS.

For more information about CGI you can refer to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831343(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)